# C# capturar mensajes de servicios de windows

Tags: c#, controller, servicio, mensajes

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación en C# para "manipular" los servicios de windows (específicamente apache).

Ya he logrado que funcione las operaciones de iniciar, detener y demás.

Lo que ahora quiero es obtener los (mensajes) resultados que devuelve dicho servicio.

Ejemplo:

- Modifico el archivo config de apache y lo guardo (una linea cualquiera) que obviamente genera un error en sintaxis de configuración.
- Intento iniciar el servicio apache y obviamente no inicia y el "mensaje" de error se registra en el visor de eventos de Windows.

**Lo que quiero**

Capturar en mi aplicación y mostrarlo en un textbox ese mensaje devuelto por apache.

este es mi código.

```
public void ManipularServicios(string serviceName, int Operation)
        {
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
            sc.ServiceName = serviceName;
            try
            {
                switch (Operation)
                {
                    case 1: sc.Stop(); ; break;
                    case 2: sc.Start(); break;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                 txtErrores.Text = e.Message;
            }
        }
```

> La parte del Catch nunca se ejecuta a pesar que el servicio no inicia que se supone es un error.

Answer (score 0):

El acción de comenzando un servico no es relacionada a si se detiene después.  Puede escuchar mensajes con el clase `EventLog` ([ver `EventLog.EventLogWritten`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten(v=vs.110).aspx) y [`EventLog.Entries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Alternativamente, puede hacer el algoritmo que `services.msc` usa: espere un corto período, luego ver si el servico sigo empezado (con [`ServiceController.Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status(v=vs.110).aspx)).